# Black screen error on navigating to ResultsPage()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxx6B.png)

I am currently working on this flutter app example as shown above.But when i tap on Calculate to navigate to next screen i get a black screen as shown below

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tuoJ.png)

Here is the GitHub Repo link: https://github.com/batman007db/bmiCalculatorApp
need Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, the error is in your `FloatingActionButton`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      heroTag: null, // here
      child: Icon(icon , color: Colors.white,),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
      onPressed: onPress,                        
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks ,mate. Can you please help me understand why i had to explicitly set heroTag property to null even if i havent used more than one FloatinButton on that screen!?

Comment: I suspect because you are creating 4 `FloatingActionButton` in the same tag within a subtree and doesn't define `Herotag` for each of them. if this answer is helpful please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Often times in navigation it's common to misstype the url of the page.

Here are my favourite steps to navigate around:

1)Add url as static cost to the arriving page (to avoid misstype)

```js
static const routeName = '/your-page';
```

2) Verify that your route on the main page is correct:

```js
routes: {
  YourPage.routeName: (ctx) => YourPage(),
},
```

3) Make sure the you call the right function:

```js
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(YourPage.routeName);
// use pushNamed if u want to be able to go back or pushReplacementNamed if u don't want to allow going back.
```

4) Check that you have imported YourPage in the page your navigating from:

Comment: thanks for help but still facing same error......console shows this error for Black screen!
════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree......